# Why Python's exec() function fails if the string to be executed contains a list comprehension?

Tags: python, jupyter, python-unittest

I use the `unittest` module to automatically test my students' code, which they write into Jupyter Notebooks.

I read the Notebook cells into `nbformat.notebooknode.NotebookNode` objects, which store the code contained in the cell as a string object under the attribute `source`. This string is assigned under the variable `cell`.

I then execute the code and perform tests as exemplified below:

```
try:

    exec(cell.source)
                        
    assert 'pattern' in locals()

except AssertionError:

    errmsg = 'The variable "pattern" has not been defined.'
```

In this case, the students are asked to (1) define a regular expression and (2) to replace matches with empty strings in a pre-existing list of strings named `y`.

The following example achieves this using a list comprehension:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"==.+==")
z = [pattern.sub('', x) for x in y]
```

This code runs without errors in the Jupyter Notebook, but the tests fail with the following error:

```
exec(self.cell.source)
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in <listcomp>
NameError: name 'pattern' is not defined
```

If I've understood correctly, the list comprehension cannot find the name `pattern` defined on the previous line.

However, the test passes if the list comprehension is replaced with a for loop, as exemplified below:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"==.+==")
z = []
for x in y:
    
    z.append(pattern.sub(repl='', string=x))
```

Why does the use of a list comprehension cause the test to fail?

Comment: I get such an error if (1) the `try`/`except` code is run in a function that is called by the main progam (so it has a new `locals()` dict with each call) and (2) the student's code is actually not run as a single monolithic block, and instead only a few statement are executed at a time with multiple calls to the execution function.  That set up is pure speculation; it will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Based off of what you've given, this works fine. There's something else missing here, but I don't think the issue is the list comprehension~

```
text = """import re
pattern = re.compile(r"==.+==")
z = [pattern.sub('', x) for x in y]"""

try:
    y = ['hi']
    exec(text)
    assert 'pattern' in locals()
except AssertionError:
    print('Error')

print(z)
```

Output:

```
['hi']
```